# Complex model binding with ajax and Razor Pages

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

Model binding with a complex type isn't binding, i've went through plenty of stack overflow posts but none have solved my issue.

I've got a working example where I directly pass the collection of objects, however I need to specify `[FromBody]`.

If I pass through a complex object with the collection then the collection comes back as null, I added a couple of properties to `MyObj` and everything binds except for the people collection.

Seems to be acting very strangely.

**MVC**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync([FromBody] List<Person> 
people){}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
                    $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Page("People")',
                    data: JSON.stringify(people),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    type: "post",
                    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    }
                });
```

Doesn't work

**MVC**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(MyObj contract){}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  var complexObject = {
     People: people,
   };

var obj = { contract: complexObject };
var data2send = JSON.stringify(obj);


                    $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Page("People")',
                    data: data2send,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    type: "post",
                    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    }
                });


example of what's data2send contains : "{"contract":{"People":[{"name": "bob"}}"
```

**C#**

```
public class MyObj 
{
   public List<Person> People {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second example you seem to have wrapped the JSON inside two objects, not one.

I will assume that by

```
{"contract":{"People":[{"name": "bob"}}
```

you actually meant

```
{"contract":{"People":[{"name": "bob"}]}}
```

because the first version is incomplete/invalid.

Anyway, this consists of  an (unnamed) object containing another object called "contract", which then contains another property called "People". However your C# `MyObj` class doesn't contain the `contract` abstraction, that's just the name you happen to have given to the parameter in the action method. I'm pretty sure you don't actually send that in the JSON, because the model binder tries to get the JSON you have sent and turn it into an instance of `MyObj`, and clearly that structure doesn't match your JSON.

I would expect that sending an object like this would be more successful:

```
{ "People":[{"name": "bob"}]}
```

To get that, the JavaScript should be

```
var complexObject = {
     People: people,
   };

//...

$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Page("People")',
  data: complexObject,
  //...etc
```

I don't think you need the other wrapper around it.